# How can I set a string the 2 html class with same name but different values

Tags: vb.net

There are 2 data-ember-action, how can I use a string for the 2 data-ember-action, I want to get the value of the 2 data-ember-action.

`
      
        
          PHP

```
    <div class="wallet__amount">
      6,000
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-ember-action="1180" class="wallet__item">
    <div class="wallet__currency">
      BTC
    </div>

    <div class="wallet__amount">
      0.25588524
    </div>
  </div>
```

`

There are 2 "data-ember-action" but different values, in html, mostly the values will change and what I want is to have a button that would get the 2 different values of it.

I am really confused on how to get this, I have no idea. Please help me

Comment: Have you read the last two questions in your question?

Comment: *edited* now, can you help me on this. I'm using vb.net

Comment: and how on earth is this related to vb.net instead of PHP ?

Comment: What is the result you want? The value of `wallet__currency` and the value of `wallet__amount`?

Comment: heres the html code: 
<div data-ember-action="1180" class="wallet__item">
<div data-ember-action="1177" class="wallet__item ">

Comment: as you can see, there are 2 data-ember-action, I want to create a button that will message me the 2 different values of the data-ember-action

Comment: Dim PageElements2 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        For Each CurElement2 As HtmlElement In PageElements2
            If CurElement2.GetAttribute("data-ember-action") = "1198" Then
                BunifuCustomLabel4.Text = CurElement2.InnerText
            End If
        Next

just like that but i'm having a hard time getting the value of the 2nd "data-ember-action"

Answer (score 0):

You should  not try to parse HTML with string methods or regex. But you could use an available HTML parser like [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex). For example with this LINQ version:

```
Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)

Dim divDataMember = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").
   FirstOrDefault(Function(node) node.Attributes("data-ember-action") IsNot Nothing)

' omitting the If divDataMember IsNot Nothing check 
Dim walletCurrency = divDataMember.Descendants("div").
    FirstOrDefault(Function(node) node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("wallet__currency", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))?.InnerText?.Trim()
Dim walletAmount = divDataMember.Descendants("div").
    FirstOrDefault(Function(node) node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("wallet__amount", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))?.InnerText?.Trim()
```

Comment: im sorry but im just new to this but is there any way that the value of the 1st data-ember-action will be shown in label1.text and the other value will be shown in label2.text?

Comment: @Rossu: sure, label1.text=walletCurrency   label2.text=walletAmount

Comment: what I mean is the value of the data-ember-action, for the walletcurrency and wallet amount, there are also 2 different values of each